# Setting data to a Riverpod AutoDispose provider prior to navigation

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a page where my app's users can create a post, optionally with some attachments. I also use this page when a user wants to edit an existing post.

I have a set of providers for each element of the post (body, id, attachments). After creating/editing a post, the user leaves the screen. If they enter the screen again, the old data should not be there anymore.

For this reason I thought of using AutoDispose providers. However, I wondered how to initialise these in the editing case: I now have this happen prior to the navigation to the page:

```dart
ref.read(postIDProvider.notifier).state = data.postID;
ref.read(linkedEventProvider.notifier).state = data.linkedEventID;
ref.read(postBodyControllerProvider.notifier).state =
                  QuillController(
                document: Document.fromJson(
                  jsonDecode(data.body) as List,
                ),
                selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
              );
context.pushNamed(
                RouteName.post.name,
                params: {'id': data.postID},
                queryParams: {'edit': 'true'},
                extra: data,
              );
```

However, these providers are only watched on the actual post page, so the data is lost, as the providers, apparently, immediately dispose themselves.

I can probably solve this problem by not making them AutoDispose providers and just set their values back to null etc. after post creation/editing, but I was wondering what the best flow is.

Comment: Use family providers to initialize them with custom data by passing that data in the form of arguments to the screen you want to navigate to. This way, the provider will only be initialized once the screen has been navigated to. 
The other way as discussed by Fetex is to reset the provider. You can use ref.invalidate(provider) in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoDispose providers are meant to be used for situations where you want the provider to be automatically disposed of when it is no longer being used. In your case, it seems like you want to keep the provider values even when the user leaves the screen, so using AutoDispose providers may not be the best option.

Instead, you could use regular providers and reset their values to null after the post creation/editing is complete. This will ensure that the old data is not displayed when the user returns to the screen. You can also use a StateNotifier to manage the state of the providers and update them accordingly.

Comment: You can also use ref.invalidate(provider) to reset the data of the provider.